# inserindo linha em branco no banco e uma com o dado certo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quando eu insiro um dado no banco sempre é registrado uma linha em branco e outra com o dado que coloquei. Já tentei reinstalar o xampp mas não funcionou testei em um outro computador e deu certo o problema esta no meu computador mas não sei o que é.

index.php

```html
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
<form action="local.php" method="POST" name="from">
    <div>
        <span >Nome do evento</span>
        <input type="text" value="" name="nomedoevento" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <span >quantidade de pessoas</span>
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'  value="" name="quantidadedepessoas" placeholder="max 150">

    </div>
    <div>
        <span >dia do evento</span>
        <input type="date" value="" name="diadoevento" >
    </div>
        <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" >cadastrar</button>

    </div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

local.php

```php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$date = date('Y-m-d');
$nome = $_REQUEST["nomedoevento"];
$data = $_REQUEST["diadoevento"];
$pessoas = $_REQUEST["quantidadedepessoas"];


?>
<h1>teste</h1>

<form action="salvar.php" method="POST" name="from">
    <div>
        <!--  COnfirmação da data nome e o local do evento  -->

        <label>Nome do Evento</label>
        <input readonly="true" name="nome-evento" type="text" value="<?php echo $nome ; ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>quantidade de pessoas</label>
        <input readonly="true" name="pessoas-evento" type="text" value="<?php echo $pessoas ; ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>data do evento</label>
        <input readonly="true" name="data-evento" type="date" value="<?php echo $data ; ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>espaço</label>
        <select name="espaco-evento">
            <?php if ($pessoas <= 7 ){ ?>
            <option type="submit" value="jus">espaço Jus 1-7 pessoas</option><br><br>
            <?php } if ($pessoas >= 7 and $pessoas <= 20 && $data >= $date) {  ?>
            <option type="submit" value="wc">espaço wc 7-20 pessoas</option><br><br>
            <?php } if ($pessoas >= 7 and $pessoas <= 20 && $data >= $date) { ?>
            <option type="submit" value="alfa">espaço alfa 7-20 pessoas</option><br><br>
            <?php } if ($pessoas >= 7 and $pessoas <= 25 && $data >= $date ) { ?>
            <option type="submit" value="ler">espaço ler 7-25 pessoas </option><br><br>
            <?php } if ($pessoas >= 25 and $pessoas <= 60 && $data >= $date) { ?>
            <option type="submit" value="cons">espaço cons 30-60 pessoas</option><br><br>
            <?php } if ($pessoas >= 70 and $pessoas <= 150 && $data >= $date ) { ?>
            <option type="submit" value="vocatio">espaço vocatio 70-150 pessoas</option><br><br>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
<button type="submit"> enviar</button>
</form>





<?php if ($data < $date){ echo "<h2> data informada e uma data invalida </h2>" ; } ?><!--data passada dpo dia atual ou inferior ao dia atual  -->
<!-- separação por numero de pessoas  para visualização do espaço-->
<?php if ($pessoas <= 7 && $data >= $date){ ?>
<button type="submit" value="jus">espaço Jus 1-7 pessoas</button><br><br>
<?php }  if ($pessoas >= 7 and $pessoas <= 20 && $data >= $date) {  ?>
<button type="submit" value="wc">espaço wc 7-20 pessoas</button><br><br>
<?php } if ($pessoas >= 7 and $pessoas <= 20 && $data >= $date) { ?>
<button type="submit" value="alfa">espaço alfa 7-20 pessoas</button><br><br>
<?php } if ($pessoas >= 7 and $pessoas <= 25 && $data >= $date) { ?>
<button type="submit" value="ler">espaço ler 7-25 pessoas </button><br><br>
<?php } if ($pessoas >= 25 and $pessoas <= 60 && $data >= $date) { ?>
<button type="submit" value="cons">espaço cons 30-60 pessoas</button><br><br>
<?php } if ($pessoas >= 70 and $pessoas <= 150 && $data >= $date) { ?>
<button type="submit" value="vocatio">espaço vocatio 70-150 pessoas</button><br><br>
<?php } if($pessoas > 150 and $data >= $date) {echo " <h2>nao tem espaço</h2>" ;} ?>
<!--  -->
```

salvar.php

```php
<?php
include("config.php");

$name = $_POST["nome-evento"];
$people = $_POST["pessoas-evento"];
$dates = $_POST["data-evento"]
$space = $_POST["espaco-evento"};
$sql = "INSERT INTO $space (nome_evento,pessoas_evento, dia_evento, espaco_evento) VALUES ('{$name}','{$people}','{$dates}','{$space}')";

            $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

            if($result==true){
                print "<div class='alert alert-success'>Conseguiu cadastrar com sucesso!</div>";
            }else{
                print "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Não possível cadastrar</div>";
            }


?>
```

config.php

```php
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $base = "salascbpc";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $base);

    //opcional: mostrar o erro caso não consiga conectar
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Error: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas não seria bom você pôr um if(isset("button")) antes do código no INSERT INTO?

Comment: como assim antes da variável ?  if(isset("button")){ $sql = "INSERT INTO $space (nome_evento,pessoas_evento, dia_evento, espaco_evento) VALUES ('{$name}','{$people}','{$dates}','{$space}')";} tipo assim ?

Comment: Assim, if(isset($_POST['submit'])){....teu código inteiro PHP entra aqui e, no fim, } (fecha a chave) para encerrar

Comment: eu coloquei e nao deu certo ainda fica colocando uma linha em branco toda vez que cadastro. quando dou o comando pra editar tambem a linha fica em branco como se nao tivese o que que editar .. ela nao fica null ela fica em branco mesmo

Comment: Tenta pôr também, além do isset, a instrução !empty (exclamação + empty) para testar o valor do submit

Comment: ainda nao deu certo=s .. descobri tambem se eu fizer um update os dados que estao certos ficam em branco nao ta atualizando  so trocando pra em branco. coloquei um print no final pra saber se o sql da query de updade tava certo e ta indo certinho mas no banco a linha "some" fica tudo em branco.